# Scala default parameters and null

Tags: scala

I have a method like this:

```
def aMethod(param: String = "asdf") = {
    ...
}
```

If the method is called as follows, then param is given the default value "asdf":

```
aMethod() ...
```

But what I would like, is that if the method is called with `null`, then the default value would also be applied:

```
aMethod(null)  //inside the method, I can use `param` and it has the value "asdf".
```

Whats the best way to do this in Scala?  I can think of pattern matching or a simple `if` statement.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Pattern matching

```
def aMethod(param: String = null) {
    val paramOrDefault = param match {
        case null => "asdf"
        case s => s
    }
}
```

## Option (implicitly)

```
def aMethod(param: String = null) {
    val paramOrDefault = Option(param).getOrElse("asdf")
}
```

## Option (explicitly)

```
def aMethod(param: Option[String] = None) {
    val paramOrDefault = param getOrElse "asdf"
}
```

The last approach is actually the most idiomatic and readable once you get use to it.

Comment: Is there a way to implicitly convert to an Option?  Sure I could write my own def, but is there one in the API already?

Comment: @JohnSmith: you mean something like: `implicit def obj2Option[T](t: T) = Option(t)`? I think this is a bit too fragile/dangerous to be part of standard implicit conversions, I don't know of any such.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz please see my answer, as this solution, at a closer examination, will have negative impact on Scala dev tools and will have the potential to break the code whenever inheritance is involved.

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to address characteristics mentioned in @VladGudim 's solution e.g.:  `* The method definition clearly indicates the parameter's default value.; * usage in traits, etc.` ; please clarify if it does.  Are there any advantages of your method over @VladGudim 's

Answer (score 6):

```
def aMethod(param: String = null) = { 
  val p = 
    if(param == null)
      "asdf"
     else
       param

  println(p) 
}
```

But the question must be asked: why allow `null`?  Would `Option` be possible in your case?  For this you could do:

```
def aMethod(param: Option[String]) = { 
  val p = param.getOrElse("asdf")    
  println(p)
}
```

This makes it clear that your method expects the possibility of a "null" argument.

Answer (score 6):

If the method has just one or two default parameters that can be set to `null` consider this pattern:

```
// please note that you must specify function return type
def aMethod (x:String = "asdf"):String = if (x==null) aMethod() else {
    // aMethod body ...
    x 
}
```

There are some benefits:

- The method definition clearly indicates the parameter's default value.
- The correct default value can be picked by Scala tools, including ScalaDoc.
- There is no need to define an additional value to substitute for the original parameter within the method body - less room for mistakes, easier to reason.
- The pattern is fairly concise.

Furthermore, consider the following scenario:

```
trait ATrait {
  def aMethod (x:String = "trait's default value for x"):String
}

class AClass extends ATrait {
    ....
}
```

Clearly, here we need to extend the trait, whilst preserving the original default value. Any of the patterns that involve initially setting the parameter to `null` followed by a check and actual default value will break the contract established by the trait:

```
class AClass extends ATrait {
  // wrong, breaks the expected contract
  def aMethod(x: String = null):String = {
      val xVal = if (x == null) "asdf" else x 
      ...
  }
}
```

Indeed in this scenario the only way to preserve the original value from `ATrait` will be:

```
class AClass extends ATrait {
  override def aMethod (x:String):String = if (x==null) aMethod() else {
    ... // x contains default value defined within ATrait
  }
}
```

However, in the scenario when there are more than one or two default parameters that can be set to `null` the pattern starts getting rather messy:

```
// two parameters
def aMethod (x:String = "Hello",y:String = "World"):String = 
  if (x==null) aMethod(y=y) else
  if (y==null) aMethod(x=x) else {
    // aMethod body ...
    x + " " + y
}

// three parameters
def aMethod (x:String = "Hello",y:String = " ",z:String = "World"):String = 
  if (x==null) aMethod(y=y,z=z) else
  if (y==null) aMethod(x=x,z=z) else 
  if (z==null) aMethod(x=x,y=y) else {
    // aMethod body ...
    x + y + z
}
```

Still when overriding an existing contract this might be the only way to honour the original default values.

Comment: I really like your approach (and justification); I wish could give it more points; since I think it should be the answer.  Thanks.