# How to auto generate object when the class get no params

Tags: scala, class

So i have simple class named `Person`, this class have several fields:

```
class person {

val name:String
val abe:Int

  def generateRandom(): Person {

     // Here i want to generate Person and return
  }
}
```

So as you can see i want my class will have the option to generate `random` `Person` but i don't want to pass any params to my class, i want it to be auto.
So how can i create new `Person` object inside this `generateRandom` method and return it with both `name` and `age` fields ?
Any suggestions how to implement it ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question @david hol.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use val for name and age, so there's no other way - you have to set then in constructor. However you can make constructor private and move generator method to companion object (because it can access private constructor). The code would look like this:

```
class Person private (val name: String, val age: Int)

object Person {
  def generateRandom(): Person = {
    val randomName = ...
    val randomAge = ...
    new Person(randomName, randomAge)
  }
}

//new Person("asdas", 3) not possible

val person = Person.generateRandom()
println(person.name, person.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have `param: String = null` in your parentheses. With the accompanied `if(param == null)`... 
[Scala default parameters and null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727401/scala-default-parameters-and-null)

Answer (score 0):

It seems very simple.

Just return the new Person object from the method, adding some random value to Name and Age.